# Conditional parsing, non-standard approach

Tags: c++, parsing

Conditional parsing (aka read some tokens and return true or false).

As a solution to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228935/processing-conditional-statements), I wrote following code:

```
bool nectar_loader::resolve_conditional( const std::function<bool(const string&)> &config_contains )
{
    bool result = true;
    // My very own recursive implementation
    /*
      - each set of parenthesis is handled recursively
      - logical AND: +
      - logical OR:  |
      - logical NOT: !
      - two bools: "result" and "current"
      - "result" keeps global result, and is modified by "+"
      - "current" keeps results for "|" and "!"
      - syntax checking for invalid
    */
    bool previous_was_operator = true;
    bool current = false; // keep track of current state
    string token;
    while( next_token(token) )
    {
        conditional_operator op;
        if( map_value(conditional_operator_map, token, op) )
        {
            if( previous_was_operator )
            {
                if( op == conditional_operator::not_op )
                    current ^= current; // negate next
                else
                {
                    syntax_error( "Conditional operators \'+\', \'|\', \')\', and \'(\' must be followed by a CONFIG string." );
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch(op)
                {
                    case conditional_operator::right_parenthesis:
                        // TODO: allow conditionals without outer parenthesis of the form (a+b)|(c)
                        return result;
                    case conditional_operator::left_parenthesis: // recurse
                        return resolve_conditional( config_contains );
                    case conditional_operator::plus_op:
                        result = result && current; // "current" -> "result"
                        if( !result ) // negative when an element of a "+" expression
                        current = false; // reset "current"
                        break;
                    case conditional_operator::or_op: // combine with "current"

                    case conditional_operator::not_op: // unreachable
                        throw runtime_error( "Internal logic error in nectar_loader::resolve_conditional" );
                }
            }
            previous_was_operator = true;
        }
        else if( !previous_was_operator )
        {
            syntax_error( "In a conditional all CONFIG strings must be seperated by a conditional operator \'+\', \'|\', \')\', or \'(\'." );
            break;
        }
        else // previous was operator, so now we have a CONFIG string
        {
            // check CONFIG string, and perform a logical OR
            // TODO: check effect of "!"
            current = current || config_contains(token);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`next_token()` reads the next token, and returns `false` if this fails. `syntax_error` sets a global error status with message which is checked after calling this function. `map_value` returns true if the token can be converted to an `enum class` value (so if it is a conditional operator as defined by me). This algorithm is more flexible than a shunting yard (due to my future plans).

I have not tested this extremely well, but what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

A few comments:

```
bool nectar_loader::resolve_conditional( const std::function<bool(const string&)> &config_contains )
```

I'd generally prefer to turn this into a template, and pass the correct function type (and if I used `std::function` at all, use it only internally to store something):

```
template <class func> 
bool nextar_loader::resolve_conditional(func &config_contains) {



    bool result = true;
    // My very own recursive implementation
    /*
      - each set of parenthesis is handled recursively
      - logical AND: +
      - logical OR:  |
      - logical NOT: !
      - two bools: "result" and "current"
      - "result" keeps global result, and is modified by "+"
      - "current" keeps results for "|" and "!"
      - syntax checking for invalid
    */
```

I'd prefer to move the block comment to just above the function header. I'd also prefer more descriptive names than `result` and `current`. Given their use, I'd consider names more like "expression_value" and "subexpression_value".

```
    bool previous_was_operator = true;
    bool current = false; // keep track of current state
```

This comment seems to add nothing to our understanding of the code. I'd consider something more like: "// Assume current sub-expression is invalid until parsed." (assuming that's really why you've initialized it to `false`).

```
    string token;
    while( next_token(token) )
    {
        conditional_operator op;
        if( map_value(conditional_operator_map, token, op) )
        {
            if( previous_was_operator )
            {
                if( op == conditional_operator::not_op )
                    current ^= current; // negate next
```

Again, the comment seems to do little to assist understanding of the code. I'd probably start by pointing out that an expression like `a op1 op2 b` is valid if and only if `op2` is a unary operator (of which this grammar apparently only supports one).

```
                    case conditional_operator::plus_op:
                        result = result && current; // "current" -> "result"
```

Given that you're using it as an `and`, I'd name this `conditional_operator::and_op` (or something similar). Then name should reflect the logical meaning of the operator, not the fact that it happens to be (mis-)represented with the `+` character.

```
                        if( !result ) // negative when an element of a "+" expression
                        current = false; // reset "current"
```

This `if` statement appears redundant (at least to me). You've just set `result` to the logical `and` of `current` and `result`, so it will be `true` if and only if both inputs were already true.

```
result = current = (current && result);
```

So, both end up true if and only if both started out true. If either started out false, both end up false.

```
                        break;
                    case conditional_operator::or_op: // combine with "current"

                    case conditional_operator::not_op: // unreachable
                        throw runtime_error( "Internal logic error in nectar_loader::resolve_conditional" );
```

This looks rather like a bug. Did you really intend that `or_op` would throw an exception as unreachable, or should there be a `break` after the `or_op` case?